# How to show app in a small size on home screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift to build a mobile app. I see some Android apps support showing in a smaller size on top-right on the home screen. I wonder how I can acheive this on iOS. Does it require any kind of permission?

Below is a screenshot about `YouTube` app show on the top-right of the homescreen.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of such an app, or show a screen shot of what you mean?

Comment: @matt I have updated the post with a screenshot as an example. Please let me konw whether it makes sense to you. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, but that's Android.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking whether this can be done in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only comparable thing in iOS is for videos on an iPad — not every iPad supports it. It's called Picture In Picture.

Comment: See for example https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_standard_player

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Does this mean it only support show video in Picture In Picture on supported iPad? Can I put a non-video view in this mode?

Comment: I've answered and I've given you a link. Now you're just asking me to repeat myself.